# Using a method in another method before definition in same class?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, namespaces

This code works:

```
def funct_a():
    funct_b()
    print("this is func a")

def funct_b():
    print("this is funct_b")

funct_a()
```

But this doesn't, why?

```
class funct():
    def funct_a(self):
        funct_b()
        print("this is func a")
    def funct_b(self):
        print("this is funct b")
x = funct()
x.funct_a()
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'funct_b' is not defined
```

Why does one work but the other doesn't? If I use a undefined function in another function it works perfectly but if I use an undefined method in another method it gives me name error why?

Comment: `self.funct_b()` ?

Comment: Please post the entire traceback error here

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  You're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] (as text) showing exactly how to reproduce the issue.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 1):

### Why first code works?

because when funct_a() is called, funct_b has already been defined

### Why second code doesn't?

because by using `funct_b()` interpreter searches for a function defined outside the class scope, not the `funct` class method. use `self.funct_b()`

P.S. dont post screenshots, but paste code instead